# Mac Air 2015 with MS office for Mac

Tags: keyboard, ms-office

Today I updated MS Office on my Mac Air.  5 updates.  Went to use Word and needed to repeat a single letter for a few lines on my new doc.  Couldn't do it, had to type the same letter one at a time. A pin.   On my Windows laptop I can hold down any letter key and it will go forever.  There is a setting somewhere that I cannot find that let's you repeat the key for as long as you want on the doc.  Cannot find that setting.  Please help...thanks.

Comment: Does the problem exist in other Apps like TextEdit or is it limited to word. Also, please edit your question with the version of macOS you’re using and what version of MS office you have

Comment: Did you look at system preferences > keyboard > keyboard  > key repeat to make sure it is not set to "off"?

Comment: Default behavior on MacOS for many years now is for an accent menu to appear when you hold down many keys.  That can be turned off via a terminal command.

Comment: If your problem is confined to word, another place to ask is https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_mac